# Rendering an element on a page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an SVG element dynamically using JS and I also set the viewBox attribute to this element. When I run the code in the browser's developer tools for the first time, the viewBox attribute is saved as viewbox, which causes SVG elements to not be displayed on the page. When I edit the HTML code using developer tools and save it, only then the attribute of all SVG elements changes from viewbox to viewBox and the elements are displayed. Why does this happen in this case and how can you avoid it?

```js
let svg = document.createElement("svg"),
g = document.createElement("g"),
path = document.createElement("path");
svg.style.display = "inline-block";
svg.style.stroke = "rgb(141, 145, 145)";
svg.style.strokeWidth = "2px";
svg.style.width = "20px";
svg.style.height = "20px";
svg.style.fill = "none";
svg.style.cursor = "pointer";
g.style.transform = "translate(7px, 7px)";
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
path.setAttribute("d","M 1 1 L 19 19 M 19 1 L 1 19");
```

```html
<svg class="i9i2ocl9j89a0-m7nh2km56ijd0-7di80k634e5i0-a0lfjpa9j3490-gl66f0364dlf0-35f2847f9l1n0-iff54pl7kgbf0-194ip1lg3d70-3nb73fk63l5g" viewbox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; stroke: rgb(141, 145, 145); stroke-width: 2px; width: 20px; height: 20px; fill: none; cursor: pointer;"><g class="1njc5co3mh4k0-coa8b8dgak90-njkc501mel1e" style="transform: translate(7px, 7px);"><path d="M 1 1 L 19 19 M 19 1 L 1 19"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: Just to clarify it for OP based on @DBS 's linked answer:
What's the actual problem is that you need to create the SVG element in a way that respects the case-sensitivity of SVG attributes. Instead of using `document.createElement`, which creates an HTML element, you should use `document.createElementNS` with the SVG namespace to create a **true** SVG element. This will preserve the case-sensitivity of attributes.

Comment: I think this will be useful for me, thanks for the answer. str1ng

Comment: But it doesn't solve my problem, still SVG elements on the page are invisible. @str1ng

Comment: Reason is most likely this, you need to change it as well:   `svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
path.setAttribute("d","M 1 1 L 19 19 M 19 1 L 1 19");` to this: 
`svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 24 24");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 1 1 L 19 19 M 19 1 L 1 19");` note that we also do add this NS part to this `.setAttributeNS()` @PatrykGmyrek

Comment: Everything works, thanks for the information. ;) @str1ng